# A drastic difference in compilation time between two machines

Tags: miktex2.9, texlive-2018

I am typesetting a book with about 650 pages and little formatting beyond the TOC, chapters and sections. There is a handful of `\index` (but I do not build the index) and each of 10 chapters begins with a drop cap.

When I am working on a Linux machine with TexLive 2018 built on an AMD Phenom II @ 3.2 GHz, the compilation lasts 4 seconds. However, when I build on a Windows 10 machine with the current MikTex, built on an Intel i5 @ 3.4 GHz, the compilation takes 21 second.

On both platforms I compile by hitting F1 in TexStudio and it does its magic.

Is this a MikTex being slow issue? Is there an way to speed things up under Windows, other than by installing TexLive, which I am trying to avoid for a good and sufficient reason?

Comment: Have you tried compiling again? MikTeX downloads packages on the fly, while TeXLive contains all of them installed (unless you chose not to). This might explain the overhead.

Comment: Windows is running many threads checking for file changes as the compile progresses. Keep an eye on resource monitor and see if processes such as antivirus are testing the umpteen temporary files as they constantly change page by page and line by line. Oh for the days of TSR threading CP/M compilation would now be less than a second :-)

Comment: Why would anyone use windows? ;-)

Comment: @marmot Just because burrows have doors no need to diss the poor folks above ground

Comment: Do the two machines differ substantially in either the amount of RAM? Is the Windows machine maybe hitting a paging bottleneck?

Comment: I see a difference between miktex and texlive too. MiKTeX is currently slower than texlive (and my tex systems are on the same computer with win10).

Comment: How does the speed of the hard discs compare?